# How did it find the source code?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm testing deployment of a DLL, BeamController.dll, by calling it from a test program Caller1.

BeamController and Caller1 are both C#, .Net 4.5 programs; each in their own separate Visual Studio projects.  Caller1 is WPF.

I moved BeamController.dll to C:\temp  (**N.B. just the DLL, not the PDB**)  and in the Caller1 project I did an add reference to pick it up.   In my code in Caller1 I instantiate an instance of the BeamController class and call a method.   The relevant code is here . . .

```
using BeamController;

namespace Caller1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private CBeamController BC;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BC = new CBeamController;
            BC.SetFocusLog(1, "C:\\temp\\log.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

It builds and runs fine.   **Here's my question:**   If I run Caller1 in the debugger and I step into the method *SetFocusLog()* it steps into the source code for that method in the BeamController code.   How did it know where that source code is?   I assume some reference to it must be stored in the DLL.   What build settings for the BeamController project control this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a mixture of the DLL and matching PDB files. The PDB files actually point to the disk file and line number which is one way the debugger keeps track.

Comment: Exactly. The PDB keeps track of the original disk location of the code, as well as the code, and VS IDE is smart enough to try and load it at that location for you when debugging.

Comment: I only moved the DLL, not the PDB file.

Comment: In that case you're not telling us a whole stack of information. Like how you  started debugging it (if it wasn't by running from Visual Studio) for a start.

Comment: In the Caller1 project in Visual Studio (2010) I do a Rebuild All, then in the Debug Window "start debugging".

Comment: OK. The DLL has it's source file names actually inside it (open one up and do a search). This tells VS where the source might be. It goes and has a look; it sucessfull it shows you the source it finds.

Comment: (I assume you mean it has references to the source files inside it) How do I turn this off when I build the DLL?   I don't want customers to be able to see the names of the source files.